# Retrieving unique values only works with a specific sheet open

Tags: excel, vba, unique, unique-values

Having some issue with a simple macro. I want to replace retrieve the unique values of column B in worksheet FLMs and paste it to another sheet. It works fine normally but only when I have the FLMs worksheet open and then run the macro. However, the macro button is placed in a different sheet and when I run it from there it returns an error.

This is the code that is used:

```
    Sub GeheleMacro()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As String
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("FLMs").Range("B4:B" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets("NIET VERWIJDEREN").Range("A1"), _
    UNIQUE:=True
   End sub
```

I already tried using 'Worksheet("FLMs").Activate' after defining lastrow but that didn't work.

Comment: `lastrow` is calculated for the active sheet. If `Sheets("FLMs")` is not activated, the variable is wrongly loaded. If this is the problem, try fully qualifying the used range: `lastrow = Sheets("FLMs").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem!